# Server shows /dev/sda2 as read only

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I can't unmount it and remount it because it says "unmount and "mount" commands don't exists.

I have tried booting from an ISO with Ubuntu Desktop and repair it but it says /dev/sda2 is "clear".

Edit.

My apologies.

I'm running an Ubuntu Server 18.04. I restart it every month or so to restart the host (windows). The server is mounted in VMWare Workstation 15 Player.

When I start this server. A lot of services failed to load: [video](https://streamable.com/qz6bcw)

I can't run some commands or run services because /dev/sda2 is marked as read only.

I can't make it writable with commands like this: `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda2 /`. The command returns an error an error: `sudo: mount: order not found` I'm translating so because my server is in spanish.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like someone has deleted `/usr/bin/mount`, perhaps even the `util-linux` package or its Ubuntu equivalent. If someone had, then they may have deleted other critical software. Try an upgrade with the same version which may/should reinstall missing required packages. I would also run `fsck` on all partitions, just in case.

Comment: I've checked all partitions with `fsck`. I ended up running a Ubuntu live with an ISO file and copied all data to a HDD.